# Multi-touch events in Java on Linux: events from OS or recognize in application?

Tags: java, linux, javafx-2, multi-touch

I'm trying to implement an JavaFX application which is able to make use of touch events and multi-touch gestures. I'm working with Java8 on Linux Mint 17.

I'm using a touch foil as input device. It's eGalaxTouch device (PCAP7200 series) using an EETI eGTouch driver (eGTouchD version: 2.5). It's recognized as standard mouse input device but also creates multi-touch events (`ABS_MT_SLOT, ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID, ABS_MT_POSITION_X, ABS_MT_POSITION_Y`) which can be read from /dev/input/eventX.

Ubuntu now comes with some multi-touch support and is able to recognize gestures. Is it possible to use those OS generated events in my application and to listen to them like to mouse events with a `MouseListener`?

Or do I have to recognize gestures in my application, possibly with the help of a library like MT4J?

Since I just started to get acquainted with this stuff, I appreciate any hint or help.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried yet, but note that JavaFX also supports [GestureEvents](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/GestureEvent.html) such as     RotateEvent, ScrollEvent, SwipeEvent, ZoomEvent and probably(?) also custom events.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/package-summary.html

Comment: Ok, this sounds like the right way for me. I found this documentation [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/events/touch_events.htm), it's talking about `TouchEvent`s. Now my problem is how to get those `TouchEvent`s.

Comment: from my touch foil - I only get mouse events.

Comment: Has anyone succeeded yet? All I can find online are failure stories... which might be another term for my career if I cant figure this out :(